# Can I launch my cross platform app via not http(s) URL?

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-manifest, intentfilter, custom-scheme-url

In my Xamarin.Forms application in AndroidManfiest.Xml I have created my custom own scheme and sending parameters through it and everything is fine but the problem is I open the application via html file has `<a href="myapp://my_parameters">Open my App</a>` but I can't open that URL(`myapp://my_parameters`) via Android messages app, FB messanger app nor etc.

So is there a way to do that? open my app via a custom URL from anywhere?

Or must I use real website to deploy my URL on it and send my custom scheme URL from there?

P.S: I've noticed big companies like Facebook, Uber and etc send the message with an http URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following code

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("myapp://my_parameters");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I don't get your answer, My question is "myapp://my_parameters" isn't clickable from application like "Mobile Messages", "FB messenger" or etc. Is there a way to open that from applications like that or must I use real website URL and then redirect to my app from that website?

Comment: You want to open your app in other app?

Comment: I want to send SMS to some mobile number with an attached URL that open my app.